# Find X for Y on a sigmoid curve / function

Tags: graphing-functions

*Note: i write this script in javascript. But any knowledge on how to produce this function is welcome!*

In the following graph you see the s-curve or sigmoid curve. The blue line shows my value Y (y-axis) (y=75). The curve has a scale of [0,0] to [100,100]. So y is always from 0 to 100.

[scurve illustrating the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZRlc.png)

I am trying to plot the red dot on the scurve where the blue line intersects. (so find the X value for a Y value.

My function to draw the scurve is as follows:

```
function sigmoid(x)
{
    return 1 / (1 + Math.pow(Math.exp(1), -x));
}

for (let z = -6; z <= 6; z += .05) {
    let sigmoidX = x1 + (x2 - x1) * ((z + 6) / 12);
    let sigmoidY = y1 + (y2 - y1) * sigmoid(z);
}
```

Now i need a function to get a X/Y value when Y is known and X is unknown

```
function getPointOnCurve(y) {
    ... code to calc x
    return x;
}
```

UPDATE:

```
    const points = [
        { x: 0, y: 0 },
        { x: 100, y: 100 }
    ];

function getSigmoid(points) {
    let x1 = points[0].x;
    let x2 = points[1].x;
    let y1 = points[0].y;
    let y2 = points[1].y;

    let PathData = [];

    for (let z = -6; z <= 6; z += .05) {
        let sigmoidX = x1 + (x2 - x1) * ((z + 6) / 12);
        let sigmoidY = y1 + (y2 - y1) * sigmoid(z);

        var vector = new Vector2(sigmoidX, sigmoidY);
        PathData.push(vector);
    }

    return PathData;
}
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you want. Is it true that you simply want to find the coordinates where
$$
y = 75
$$
and 
$$
y = \frac{100}{1+e^{-x}}
$$
intersect? This is what I interpret "I am trying to plot the red dot on the scurve where the blue line intersects" to mean.

Comment: I think you understand correctly, i want to plot the red dot where the blue line intersects the s-curve. And my only known value is Y (y-axis) (in this case 75).

I am sorry but i don't understand how your function would give me the x (x-axis) value to get the coordinate. Can you explain in layman's terms please?

edit: please forgive my little knowledge in mathematics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you have a curve of the form
$$\tag{1}
y_1 = \frac{100}{1+e^{-x}}
$$
and a line
$$
y_2 = 75
$$
Now, you want to calculate their intersection point. This can be done easily by hand. First, equate the two to get
$$
y_1 = y_2 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad \frac{100}{1+e^{-x}} = 75
$$
We can solve the $x$-coordinate quite easily. Multiply both sides by $\frac{1+e^{-x}}{75}$ to get
$$
\frac{100}{1+e^{-x}}\left( \frac{1+e^{-x}}{75} \right) = 75 \cdot \left( \frac{1+e^{-x}}{75} \right)
$$
As you probably see, a lot of the terms cancel out and we get
$$
\frac{100}{75} = 1 + e^{-x}
$$
We are close to the solution. Subtract $1$ from both sides to get
$$
\frac{100}{75} -1 = e^{-x}
$$
or $\frac{1}{3}= e^{-x}$. This equation can be solved by taking the natural logarithm on both sides. The result is
$$
\ln{\left( \frac{1}{3} \right)} = -x
$$
Remembering the properties of logarithms, we get $\ln{\frac{1}{3}} = - \ln{3}$
and therefore
$$
x = \ln{3} \approx 1.0986
$$
Therefore, the coordinates are

> $$
> (x,y) = (\ln{3}, 75)
> $$

You can test if this is the correct answer by inserting $x=\ln{3}$ into Equation (1)

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer, i get the logic behind the steps but the X=3 is nowhere near the s curve? (see: https://ibb.co/KbCn4yw) The outcome should be something like 58 if i approx it.

Comment: I suspect that since your code includes " let sigmoidX = x1 + (x2 - x1) * ((z + 6) / 12);", the $x$ coordinate is somehow scaled. Do you have the values of x1 and x2? How about y1, y2 ?

Comment: yes i do: x1: 0, x2: 0  / y1: 100, y2: 100. (my scales are from 0 to 100 in both directions)

Comment: That's odd because in that case "x1 + (x2 - x1) * ((z + 6) / 12)" becomes identically zero ($x2-x1 = 0$) ... As I see it, your set of points sigmoidX is just a list of zeros, and sigmoidY is always equal to 100. I don't know if I'm interpreting the code wrong ...

Comment: Maybe you mean that $x2=100$ and $y1= 0$ ?

Comment: i updated my answer with my full function

Comment: Okay now it's more clear! So there is some scaling factor for $x$ ... I'll need a minute to take a look at this.

Comment: Okay so plugging in the numbers, you get the parametric equation
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{cr}
x =& 100 \frac{z+6}{12} \\
y =& 100 \cdot \text{sigmoid}(z)
\end{array}
\right.
$$
and therefore, related to my derivation, what I actually solved was $z$ and not $x$.  But $x$ can be calculated easily:
$$
x = 100 \frac{z+6}{12} = 100 \frac{\ln{3} + 6}{12} \approx 59.155
$$
I think this should be a satisfying answer to you.

Comment: Matti P. Thank you! You have been a great help to me. Thanks for your devotion.

Comment: You're welcome. I hope that you learned from this so that you know how to solve these problems in general. You can mark my answer as accepted.